# Extremely low power sensors powered from mains (110/220)

Tags: low-power, efficiency, ac-dc, switching-regulator, automation

I hope to find some help here with powering of sensor module. I have sensor, that was designed primary for battery usage, so it is extremelly low power, now I was aked to try this sensor also indoor with power from mains (110/220V), and here I have already spend hours on internet without any progress. I need power module that will provide the sensor with 5V, but as there will be many of them (start with 1, 2, 10, up to 1000) running 24x7 it is expected that one of biggest advantages (low power) will remain.

The Sensor:
Input voltage: 5 V (+30% -5%)
Input current: 0.005 mA (typical)
Input current on action: 5mA (typical) 10mA (max)
Sensor run time: 24x7
Sensor action: 16 minutes/day (typical) 60 minutes/day (max)

What I have found are PCB (not necessary needed) power modules that have reasonable self power consumption <50mW however they are at least 1W and require minimal load of 5 to 10% (10 to 20 mA) which is still significantly more than sensor consumption.
Then there are power source modules that have no minimal load limit, however thay have internal power consumption cca 1W which means (calculated to 1000 sensors) that power supplies will consume 24 000 W/24h and sensors will consume 0.6 W/24h which I consider as unfair :-(

Looking forward to any help.

Comment: Please explain why a USB charger is not suitable. You should only ask for product recommendations if you want your question closed so remove anything from your post that looks like a shopping question. See the [Help Center](http://http://electronics.stackexchange.com//help) for more details. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Why wouldn't a 5V wall wart work?

Comment: 5V wall charger has standby power cca 250mW depending on type, but I did not manage to find out what is the minimal load. I have measured the voltage of the ones I have at home and it is far above 5V I measured between 7 and 8 volts.  To the recommendations: I'm not asking about product recommendation, I'm asking if there is technology available for power source for given sensor that is power efficient

Comment: Is this sensor ever touched or easily accessible while it's connected & in use? Does its power supply need to provide isolation from the mains supply?

Comment: A *regulated* "wall wart" power supply, like those USB chargers, will under no condition output more than about 5.25V. - I do understand your issue with wasting 99% of the power to standby though.

Comment: Idea #1: Connect multiple sensors to a single power supply.

Comment: @brhans The sensor is cca 2 to 3 meters above the terrain and is hard to reach. It is also located in metal enclosure so protected against accidental touch. No isolation or other protection needed, the sensors costs cca 5 USD/piece so some 'loss' by error of power source can be accepted

Comment: Idea #2: Only connect to the mains intermittently, charge a capacitor, disconnect from mains until cap is discharged below threshold, then connect again &c.

Comment: @JimmyB The Idea #1 can not be implemented due to missing (and not acceptable to change) cabling - one of the reasons the idea with 'stand-alone' senors is in place Idea #2 have never tried and not investigated in this way will do so and let you know

Comment: Example: 100uF cap, 6V input @ 50mA, 5V threshold can run the sensor about 20 seconds in standby (5uA) and recharge it to 6V in a few ms.

Comment: Or use some super capacitors (Gold Cap,...). 0.1F will already get you pretty far. - I admit that I don't have a circuit for connecting/disconnecting mains as required though.

Comment: @JimmyB: Thank you for the idea, had a brief look to the efficiency http://www.powerguru.org/ultracapacitor-efficiency/ and seems at cca 80%, plus the management of charge/discharge... Must calculate, think more but seems like worth to investigate. On the sensor I have some computing power left so if inteligently designed the sensor can monitor and automatically (dis)connect the mains dependingon charge level. But will require significant design effort.

Comment: If isolation is not an issue you could use a cheap transformerless capacitor based power supply (see: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00954A.pdf or http://www.electroschematics.com/5678/capacitor-power-supply/).

Comment: Might energy harvesting (e.g. small solar, temperature difference, vibration) be a solution? This would also eliminate the need to connect to a wall outlet or mains cabling.

Comment: If you actually have a uC in the sensor, an ADC input and a Triac could be the building blocks for the circuit. Just need some bootstrap circuitry to get the initial charge into the cap. Efficiency of the components should not be an issue I think, because even a 10% total efficiency is much better than the 0.01% or so of the simple implementation with off-the-shelf wall warts.

Comment: @Stefan Isn't transformerless the opposite of energy efficient?

Comment: @Stefan +1 for a cool alternative. You could just sip power when needed

Comment: @JimmyB Yes, transformerless mainly wastes power on the reactive or resistive resistance. But if the power drawn is very small the power wasted is also quite small. And with reactive resistance this is not real power. Although it messes up your cos-phi...

Comment: I entered "low power offline switching power supply" into a search engine. As an example the first applicable entry is this: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP1015-D.PDF, with power down to 80mW.

Comment: @rioraxe, Yes solutions like this areavailable (in your case the best scenario would be cca 60mW on standby, I'm searching for soluiton to supply sensor which has 0.025mW standby and my expectation is that power source for sensor will internally ocnsume less than the supplier power, after studying some manuals and reference circuitry I do not think it is feasible, however will check the idea below what is the power consumption

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it with suitable X1 rated cap and 3kV rated R (or equiv (6*500V) and two 5.6V Zeners   ESR of gen purp. 220uF cap 1 Ohm

[image]

[Simulation (java)](http://www.falstad.com/circuit-java/#%24+12+2.4999999999999998E-5+18.278915558614752+50+5.0+48%0Av+176+288+176+160+0+1+60.0+168.0+0.0+3.141592653589793+0.5%0Aw+176+288+304+288+0%0Aw+368+320+240+320+0%0Aw+240+224+240+320+0%0Az+240+224+304+160+1+0.7+5.6%0Az+304+160+368+224+1+0.7+5.6%0Ar+176+160+240+160+0+1000.0%0Aw+368+224+464+224+0%0Ar+512+224+512+320+0+500.0%0Aw+368+320+512+320+0%0Ad+304+288+368+224+1+0.7%0Ad+240+224+304+288+1+0.7%0Ac+240+160+304+160+0+2.7E-7+160.8815228102865%0Ar+240+112+304+112+0+1000000.0%0Aw+240+112+240+160+0%0Aw+304+112+304+160+0%0Ag+160+320+160+352+0%0Ac+368+224+368+304+0+1.9999999999999998E-4+4.99351653523226%0As+464+224+512+224+0+0+false%0Ar+368+304+368+320+0+1.0%0Ao+17+64+0+290+10.0+0.00625+0+-1%0A)

Comment: It should work not only with 120 V AC, but also with 220 V AC.

Comment: The advantage of this design over previous linked solution is less ripple, and smaller X1 cap, otherwise, compromise regulation error for Line range.  @Uwe to enable universal use, without switch, needs SMPS ...not possible this way without bad regulation error

Comment: What is the efficiency of this solution? It always seems to me that, with simple power supply, if you drain a mA @5V, you end-up draining a mA directly from the mains, am I mistaken ?

Comment: yes but at 70x the voltage drop at 230Vac or  350Vdc, so best case 1/70 W/VAR ratio.. not a big true loss but large X1 caps for VAR divider, 1K is only for caps without self-healing due to surges.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that there is no galvanic isolation, so this circuit (and everything connected to it) should only be used within doubly-insulated devices to be safe.

Comment: good point, although assumed, there are also more requirements for offline chargers to be certified.  Volume cost of this solution is in the $2 range for bom incl. connectors

Comment: @TonyStewart Thank you will try this circuit and measure the result